# No launcher activity found.! The launch will only sync the application package on the device.!

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am facing the problem plzzz help me out. Here is my manifest.xml file.
Plz help me out.......your help is highly appreciated....

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hello.myandroidnew"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"  android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.myandroidnew.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".second"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

Change your intent filter to the following:

```
<intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

The difference is the action. It must be `android.intent.action.MAIN` in order to be listed in the launcher.

Comment: but the name of the activity is MAINACTIVITY instead of MAIN.

Comment: That does not matter. You are setting the activity name at the beginning of activity tag under name. The action is something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the action name properly so that android know that it is the main activity. Change

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />
```

to

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
```

**update:-**
You specify name of the class in

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.myandroidnew.MainActivity"
```

Docs of  `"android.intent.action.MAIN"` specifies :-

```
public static final String ACTION_MAIN
Added in API level 1
Activity Action: Start as a main entry point, does not expect to receive data.
Input: nothing
Output: nothing
Constant Value: "android.intent.action.MAIN"
```

Thus you can see that `action.MAIN` tells android that it is the main entry point i.e. the default activity that is to be shown when the app starts.

Comment: but the name of the activity is MAINACTIVITY instead of MAIN